# Get all childrens of a parent ordered by level

Tags: c#, tree

I have this table ordered by level

```
name    parentId    id  level
Dep 1   0           1    0  
Dep 2   1           2    1  
Dep 6   2           6    2  
Dep 4   1           4    1  
Dep 5   4           5    2
Dep 3   0           3    0
```

What's the best approach to get all childrens of a parent ?. I thought of using a dictionnary to store all the ids and then create a recursive function to search for all the childrens of each parent. But since it's already sorted by levels, do i really need a recursive function or a i can just do it in an iterative way ?

**Result Expected :**

```
[  
   {
     "id"   : "1", 
     "name" : "Dep1",
     "children": [
        {
           "id"  : "2", 
           "name" : "Dep2",
           "children": [
              {
               "id"  : "6", 
               "name" : "Dep6"
              }
           ]
        }
      ]
     "id"   : "4", 
     "name" : "Dep4",
     "children": [
        {
           "id"  : "5", 
           "name" : "Dep5"
        }
     ]
     {
     "id"   : "3", 
     "name" : "Dep3"
     }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take this approach:

```
List<Data> data = new List<Data>()
{
    new Data() { Name = "Dep 1", ParentId = 0, Id = 1, Level = 0 },
    new Data() { Name = "Dep 2", ParentId = 1, Id = 2, Level = 1 },
    new Data() { Name = "Dep 6", ParentId = 2, Id = 6, Level = 2 },
    new Data() { Name = "Dep 4", ParentId = 1, Id = 4, Level = 1 },
    new Data() { Name = "Dep 5", ParentId = 4, Id = 5, Level = 2 },
    new Data() { Name = "Dep 3", ParentId = 0, Id = 3, Level = 0 },
};

var lookup = data.ToLookup(x => x.ParentId);

List<Result> GetChildren(int parentId) =>
    lookup[parentId]
        .Select(c => new Result()
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            Name = c.Name,
            Children = GetChildren(c.Id)
        })
        .ToList();

List<Result> result = GetChildren(0);
```

This gives:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Dep 1",
    "Children": [
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "Dep 2",
        "Children": [
          {
            "Id": 6,
            "Name": "Dep 6",
            "Children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": 4,
        "Name": "Dep 4",
        "Children": [
          {
            "Id": 5,
            "Name": "Dep 5",
            "Children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "Dep 3",
    "Children": []
  }
]
```

I agree that this would need to be tested on a large data set to see if it has a memory or computation limit.

Comment: definitely,  the .ToLookup is the winner (64 ms vs 980 ms). Thanks for both of you :)

Comment: Yes, it should produce a solution that has complexity `O(2n)` rather than `O(n^2)` using the `IndexOf` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Following Solution will work for you. You need to install [NewtonSoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) nuget package for serializing object to json.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Data> data = new List<Data>();
        data.Add(new Data() { Id = 1, Name = "Dep 1", ParentId = 0, Level = 0 });
        data.Add(new Data() { Name = "Dep 2", ParentId = 1, Id = 2, Level = 1 });
        data.Add(new Data() { Name = "Dep 6", ParentId = 2, Id = 6, Level = 2 });
        data.Add(new Data() { Name = "Dep 4", ParentId = 1, Id = 4, Level = 1 });
        data.Add(new Data() { Name = "Dep 5", ParentId = 4, Id = 5, Level = 2 });
        data.Add(new Data() { Name = "Dep 3", ParentId = 0, Id = 3, Level = 0 });

        var result = data
                    .Where(c=>c.Level == 0)
                    .Select(c => new Result
                    {
                        Id = c.Id,
                        Name = c.Name,
                        Children = GetChildren(data, c.Id)
                    }).ToList();

        string resultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static List<Result> GetChildren(List<Data> records, int parentId)
    {
        return records
                .Where(c => c.ParentId == parentId)
                .Select(c => new Result
                {
                    Id = c.Id,
                    Name = c.Name,
                    Children = GetChildren(records, c.Id)
                }).ToList();
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Result> Children { get; set; }
}
```

**Result**

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Dep 1",
    "Children": [
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "Dep 2",
        "Children": [
          {
            "Id": 6,
            "Name": "Dep 6",
            "Children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": 4,
        "Name": "Dep 4",
        "Children": [
          {
            "Id": 5,
            "Name": "Dep 5",
            "Children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "Dep 3",
    "Children": []
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, but i dont think this recursive solution will be good for large data around 200 000 rows and up. I'm sure it should be a way to make it non-recursive using a dictionnary or a hashtable since it's already ordered by level. Your solution is good if my data are not ordered

Comment: @lory As you can find in my solution that I am processing 0 level data at first and then going for their children. Ultimately, you will have to iterate your records even  using a dictionnary or a hashtable. I assume that data is coming from database.

Comment: Operation can be heavy in case you are fetching data from database then storing in dictionary / hashtable and performing some logic.

Comment: yes i will fetch data from sql database. So i will take the data from the database and put them in a dictionnary or a list and then i can use linq methods.